# How to get 3rd level categories in category module opencart 2.0.3

Tags: php, opencart-module

I am trying to get 3rd level category on category page left sidebar but I am unable to get child id, here is my code to get 3rd level category:

```
$children_lv3_data = array();

if ($child['category_id'] == $data['child_id']) {
    $children_lv3 = $this->model_catalog_category->getCategories($child['category_id']);

    foreach ($children_lv3 as $child_lv3) {
        $filter_data_lv3 = array(
            'filter_category_id'  => $child_lv3['category_id'],
            'filter_sub_category' => true
        );

        $children_lv3_data[] = array(
            'category_id' => $child_lv3['category_id'],
            'name'  => $child_lv3['name'] . ($this->config->get('config_product_count') ? ' (' . $this->model_catalog_product->getTotalProducts($filter_data_lv3) . ')' : ''),
            'href'  => $this->url->link('product/category', 'path=' . $category['category_id'] . '_' . $child['category_id'] . '_' . $child_lv3['category_id'])
        );
    }
}
```